# Product of polynomials to distribute 10 identical balls to 2 boys & 2 girls where each boy gets at least one ball and each girl gets at least 2 balls

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

I am asked

How many ways are there to distribute 10 identical balls among 2 boys and 2 girls, if each boy should get at least 1 ball and each girl should get at least 2 balls?  Express the answer as a coefficient of a suitable power of x in a suitable product of polynomials.

I am unable to understand how I can use products of polynomials to answer this question and how to proceed.

Ive set up something like

$(B^1+B^2+B^3+B^4+B^5)^2(G^2+G^3+G^4+G^5)^2$

But I do not know when to terminate each factor as to know when I have allocated all 10 balls-- I don't want to go over the 10 balls.

Comment: @Bulbasaur the "atleast" is throwing me off, i don't know what power I should end off on when making each part of the gf. I have something like $(B+B^2+B^3 + B^4+B^5 + ...)^2(G^2+G^3+G^4+G^5+...)^2$, but unsure how to approach the "..."

Comment: I see, so setting it up before in terms of what you've provided, we can just expand $(\frac{1}{1-x})^2(\frac{x^2}{1-x})^2$ and find the coefficient of $x^{10}$?

Comment: @Bulbasaur perfect. got it, thank you! if you'd like to put your hint as an answer I'll accept it

Comment: you are welcome!! I glad to help you..

Comment: I deleted the comments because of the answer is writen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To work over generating functions, you must write the variables as the same. For example , use only $x$ instead of $B$ and $G$.When we comes to your problem such that "But I do not know when to terminate each factor as to know when I have allocated all 10 balls". For this question , the terminal point is not important , the generating function will handle it automatically.

For easier calculation , you can write them like $$\bigg(\frac{x}{1-x} \bigg)^2 \times \bigg(\frac{x^2}{1-x} \bigg)^2. $$

What you need to do is just finding the coefficent of $x^{10}.$

Whats more , as you see the foregoing expression can be writen by $$x^6 \times \bigg(\frac{1}{1-x}\bigg)^4,$$  so just find the coefficient of $x^4$ in $$\bigg(\frac{1}{1-x} \bigg)^4.$$

You can use  wolfram-alpha for it!